# Merge overlapping date intervals into big intervals providing uniquness of some id inside merged group

Tags: postgresql

I have some date intervals, each interval is characterized by known "prop_id". My goal is to merge overlapping intervals into big intervals, while keeping the uniquness of "prop_id" inside the merged group. I have some code that helps me to get big intervals, but I 've no idea how to keep condition of uniquness (. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
________1      ________1
     ___________2
      

________1     |________1
     _________|__2

[1,2]_________|________[1,2]
```

For SQLFiddle:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ido_seq;
create table slots ( 
                    ido integer NOT NULL default nextval('ido_seq'), 
                    begin_at date, 
                    end_at date, 
                    prop_id integer);
ALTER SEQUENCE ido_seq owned by slots.ido;


INSERT INTO slots (ido, begin_at, end_at, prop_id) VALUES
  (0, '2014-10-05', '2014-10-10', 1),
  (1, '2014-10-08', '2014-10-15', 2),
  (2, '2014-10-13', '2014-10-20', 1),
  (3, '2014-10-21', '2014-10-30', 2);
 
-- disired output:
-- start,      end,        props  
-- 2014-10-05, 2014-10-12, [1,2] --! the whole group is (2014-10-05, 2014-10-20, [1,2,1]), but props should be unique
-- 2014-10-13, 2014-10-20, [1,2] --so, we obtain 2 ranges instead of 1, each one with 2 generating prop_id
-- 2014-10-21, 2014-10-30  [2]
```

How do we get it:
if two date intervals overlap, we merge them. The first ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-10'] and second ['2014-10-08', '2014-10-15'] have part ['2014-10-08', '2014-10-10'] in common. So we can merge them to ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-15']. The generalizing props are unique - OK. The next one ['2014-10-13', '2014-10-20'] is overlapping with previously calculated ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-15'], but we can't merge them without breaking the condition of uniquness. So we are to split the big interval ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-20'] into 2 small using the begin date of repeating prop ('2014-10-13'), but keeng the condition and receive ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-12'] (as '2014-10-13' minus 1 day) and ['2014-10-13', '2014-10-20'] both generalizing by props 1 and 2.

My attempt to get merged intervals (not keeping uniqueness condition):

```
SELECT min(begin_at), max(enddate), array_agg(prop_id) AS props
FROM  (
  SELECT *,  
    count(nextstart > enddate OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY begin_at DESC, end_at DESC) AS grp
  FROM  (
    SELECT 
       prop_id
       , begin_at
       , end_at
       , end_at AS enddate
       , lead(begin_at) OVER (ORDER BY begin_at, end_at) AS nextstart
    FROM slots
  ) a
)b
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Comment: I don't understand the merging.  How does the merged interval start at 2014-10-05 when prop_id 2 doesn't start until 2014-10-08?

Comment: Sorry for not well detailed description. I've just updated it.

Answer (score 1):

The right solution here is probably to use a recursive CTE to find the large intervals no matter how many smaller intervals need to be combined, and then to remove the intervals that we do not need.

```
with recursive intervals(idos, begin_at,end_at,prop_ids) as(
  
  select array[ido], begin_at, end_at, array[prop_id]
  from slots
  union
  select i.idos || s.ido 
   , least(s.begin_at, i.begin_at)
   , greatest(s.end_at, i.end_at)
   , i.prop_ids || s.prop_id
  from intervals i 
  join slots s 
      on (s.begin_at, s.end_at) overlaps (i.begin_at, i.end_at)
       and not (i.prop_ids && array[s.prop_id]) --check that the prop id is not already in the large interval
   where s.begin_at < i.begin_at --to avoid having double intervals
  )
  select * from intervals i
   --finally, remove the intervals that are a subinterval of an included interval
  where not exists(select 1 from intervals i2 where i2.idos @> i.idos
                   and i2.idos <> i.idos);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not as simple, because "distinct" will give us a "dishonest" uniqueness and big interval ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-20'] will include small intervals with prop_id=1 twice in reality.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, that's cute. But one more difficulty rests: by task condition we have to deal not with given intervals "as is", but also wth their parts. The output for given example (the first 3 intervals) will be ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-15'] and ['2014-10-08', '2014-10-20']. If we look at input again we'll notice that in fact output-interval ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-15'] includes intervals ['2014-10-05', '2014-10-10'],['2014-10-08', '2014-10-15'] and a ['2014-10-13', '2014-10-15']  as a part of ['2014-10-13', '2014-10-20'], so parts are [1,2,1] :( Maybe we have to pre-split "slots" some how..

Comment: I have no more time to spend on this today, but once you have the large intervals, you can:
1. join to the original list of slots to find slots that overlap and have intersection prop_id but non-intersection ido
2. for each of these pairs of intervals, find the resulting min and max if the ranges overlap (either with case statement, or using range subtraction) 
3. aggregate to one row per interval record, taking the smallest possible range. 

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try to do it and post the decision later.